# How to scrape location data from MarineTraffic

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape the location data of a vessel using RStudio:

Here is the link- 
https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:199293

My code:

```
"https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:199293" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("div#MuiTypography-displayInline")
```

Any suggestions on how this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I go to the page you linked in my browser, open inspector tools, and head to the tab 'network', I see a lot of requests that are sent out when you visit the page.
Among those requests are:

https://www.marinetraffic.com/vesselDetails/voyageInfo/shipid:199293
https://www.marinetraffic.com/vesselDetails/latestPosition/shipid:199293
https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/vesselDetails/vesselInfo/shipid:199293

Those return nicely formatted JSON files that you should be able to parse with the `jsonlite` package:

```
library(jsonlite)

"https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/vesselDetails/vesselInfo/shipid:199293" %>%
  read_json()
```